# iText7 typography IndexOutOfBoundsException on Bengli Text

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7, typography

I am trying to create pdf of Bengli text using iText7.
Other text seems working fine but one.

```
PdfFont font = null;
try {
     font = PdfFontFactory.createFont("SolaimanLipi.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}    
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("ওয়ার্ড ২৭").setFont(font).setFontSize(18);
doc.add(p);
```

Error I am getting:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TypographyUtils.callMethod(TypographyUtils.java:252)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TypographyUtils.callMethod(TypographyUtils.java:240)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TypographyUtils.applyOtfScript(TypographyUtils.java:120)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TextRenderer.applyOtf(TextRenderer.java:568)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.LineRenderer.applyOtf(LineRenderer.java:1146)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.LineRenderer.layout(LineRenderer.java:143)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.ParagraphRenderer.layout(ParagraphRenderer.java:205)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.RootRenderer.addChild(RootRenderer.java:134)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.RootElement.createAndAddRendererSubTree(RootElement.java:377)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.RootElement.add(RootElement.java:106)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.Document.add(Document.java:160)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TypographyUtils.callMethod(TypographyUtils.java:246)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at com.itextpdf.typography.ordering.indic.IndicCluster.get(IndicCluster.java:69)
    at com.itextpdf.typography.ordering.indic.IndicShaper.finalReordering(IndicShaper.java:901)
    at com.itextpdf.typography.shaping.Shaper.applyIndicScript(Shaper.java:237)
    at com.itextpdf.typography.shaping.Shaper.applyOtfScript(Shaper.java:99)
```

I am using `iText 7.1.2` and `typography 2.0.0`. 
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very similar issue has been reported by other users for the cluster র্য, and that one has been fixed. However, there is no official release yet that contains this bugfix.

You can try testing with the latest successful build of the project, which you can download from https://repo.itextsupport.com/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/simple/General/snapshot/com/itextpdf/typography/2.0.1-SNAPSHOT

The next official release of the typography module, which will contain this fix, will be released in July.